# Pattern matching in byte arrays

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have two byte array which each contain a series of values like:

```
byte[] b = {50,60,70,80,90,10,20,1,2,3,4,5,50,2,3,1,2,3,4,5};
byte[] b2 = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

I can compare these two arrays and look for the equal values using LinQ methods. In this way, if I make a comparison between these two arrays, the result would be an index of b array where a value in an index of b2 array is a match.

I've been trying to exactly find the range where b2 array is recurring in b array. I mean

```
if (TheLenghtOfSearch==5) {Now the indexes of two regions must be return }
Result ->(7, 11), (15, 19)

if (TheLenghtOfSearch==2) {Now the indexes of around 9 regions where the two consecutive values in b2 recurred in b must be returned}
Result ->(7, 8), (15, 16), (8, 9), (13, 14), (16, 17), (9, 10), (17, 18), (10, 11), (18, 19)
```

I guess the solution is more mathematical.

Comment: What kind of result you are trying to get in your example?

Comment: Indexes in the b array

Comment: You can turn the byte array to a string and do a string search

Comment: the list of indexex in b array which are equal to some value in b2?

Comment: `Shai Aharoni` bad move!

Comment: The problem is more complicated, sometimes I don't know the depth of the search, and in this ways the exact values can be find not the pattern, for example if the search depth is 2 then I'm not looking for the the whole pattern, so the program must be able to iterate and pair each value which is kind of mathematical problem

Comment: how can you return the indexes if you convert the byte array to string ? this solution will cause some problems

Comment: what is a search depth and how it should affect the result?

Comment: @Maris, not exactly, in this way (for the first if) the program may return more than two ranges (ex index 7-12)

Comment: I mean if the lenght of the pattern array is 5, the I'm looking for exact match , but if it is 2, then I'm looking for all the consecutive combinations of the values

Comment: for example in this case if the depth is 2 : it would be (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5) and the same thing for other depths

Comment: Check my answer. It works just as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use List, not array, because it have more helpers for this kind of operations.
As I understand depth = the amount of items that have to be equals in each array. This one works, check this out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<byte> b = new List<byte>() { 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 10, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 50, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<byte> b2 = new List<byte>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        SmartComparer comparer = new SmartComparer();
        //Setting the depth here, now the depth is = 5
        var result = comparer.CompareArraysWithDepth(b, b2, 5);
        foreach (var keyValuePair in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("b[{0}]->b[{1}] are equal to b2[{2}]->b2[{3}]", keyValuePair.Key.Key,
                                            keyValuePair.Key.Value, keyValuePair.Value.Key, keyValuePair.Value.Value));
        }
    }
}

public class SmartComparer
{
    public Boolean CompareRange(List<byte> a, List<byte> b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// |
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <param name="depth"></param>
    /// <returns>Key->range in 'a', Value->range in 'b'</returns>
    public List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>> CompareArraysWithDepth(
        List<byte> a, List<byte> b, int depth)
    {
        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>>();
        if (depth > b.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Array 'b' item count should be more then depth");
        if(a.Count<b.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Array 'a' item count should be more then Array 'b' item count");
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.Count - depth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= b.Count - depth; j++)
            {
                if (CompareRange(a.GetRange(i, depth), b.GetRange(j, depth)))
                {
                    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, i + depth-1), new KeyValuePair<int, int>(j, j + depth-1)));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**ADDED**

The result of this operation for depth = 3:

```
b[7]->b[9] are equal to b2[0]->b2[2]
b[8]->b[10] are equal to b2[1]->b2[3]
b[9]->b[11] are equal to b2[2]->b2[4]
b[15]->b[17] are equal to b2[0]->b2[2]
b[16]->b[18] are equal to b2[1]->b2[3]
b[17]->b[19] are equal to b2[2]->b2[4]
```

The result of this operation for depth = 2:

```
b[7]->b[8] are equal to b2[0]->b2[1]
b[8]->b[9] are equal to b2[1]->b2[2]
b[9]->b[10] are equal to b2[2]->b2[3]
b[10]->b[11] are equal to b2[3]->b2[4]
b[13]->b[14] are equal to b2[1]->b2[2]
b[15]->b[16] are equal to b2[0]->b2[1]
b[16]->b[17] are equal to b2[1]->b2[2]
b[17]->b[18] are equal to b2[2]->b2[3]
b[18]->b[19] are equal to b2[3]->b2[4]
```

The result of this operation for depth = 5:

```
b[7]->b[11] are equal to b2[0]->b2[4]
b[15]->b[19] are equal to b2[0]->b2[4]
```

Comment: Maris, again it finds only the last pattern. There may a lot of patterns which I don't know where they are

Comment: Added to my answer the result given to console. It returns all entries of pattern!

Comment: Also notice, that in the result I use the 'depth'=3

Comment: If it's not a result you are trying to get, then i completly misunderstand you. Please provide the expected asnwer for this 'b' and this 'b2' with depth = 3, so I can understand what you trying to get

Comment: Imagine a recurring pattern for N times in the form of a sequence of numbers. I want to list out all the ranges where this pattern is recurring not just a specific range of indexes, this is the problem I have faced, I have no problem comparing the two arrays as I said in my question.

Comment: Maris, for example the result for my first if is , [7,11] and then [15,19] now if the array is bigger then I wanna go on for more

Comment: My code gives the result you just said

Comment: choice the right depth. updated my answer, now it should be clear to you

Comment: yes you'er right maris

Comment: I've been thinking too much forgot to put the result in a loop, thank you very very much for your priceless help.

Answer (score 0):

If Linq is not a absolutly required option for you, you can obtain the result by for loop:

```
public static IList<Tuple<int, int>> RecurringIndexes(Byte[] master, Byte[] toFind, int length) {
  List<Tuple<int, int>> result = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

  // Let's return empty list ... Or throw appropriate exception
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, master))
    return result;
  else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, toFind))
    return result;
  else if (length < 0)
    return result;
  else if (length > toFind.Length)
    return result;

  Byte[] subRegion = new Byte[length];

  for (int i = 0; i <= toFind.Length - length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j)
      subRegion[j] = toFind[j + i];

    for (int j = 0; j < master.Length - length + 1; ++j) {
      Boolean counterExample = false;

      for (int k = 0; k < length; ++k)
        if (master[j + k] != subRegion[k]) {
          counterExample = true;

          break;
        }

      if (counterExample)
        continue;

      result.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(j, j + length - 1));
    }
  }

  return result;
}

....

byte[] b = {50,60,70,80,90,10,20,1,2,3,4,5,50,2,3,1,2,3,4,5};
byte[] b2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Returns 2 patterns: {(7, 11), (15, 19)}
IList<Tuple<int, int>> indice5 = RecurringIndexes(b, b2, 5); 
// Return 9 patterns: {(7, 8), (15, 16), (8, 9), (13, 14), (16, 17), (9, 10), (17, 18), (10, 11), (18, 19)}
IList<Tuple<int, int>> indice2 = RecurringIndexes(b, b2, 2);
```

Comment: Dmitry, the list is always empty which means the patterns cannot be found.

Comment: Well, I've run both test cases (indice5 and indice2) and got {7, 15} as I've exepected. Could you, please, provide your counter example?

Comment: This is not the result, for example (1,2,3,4,5) has been recurred two times. So the result is not 7 and , 15, I mean what about the next one and the one after, the other case would be more complex

Comment: @Jack: it's quite difficult task to find out what is a right answer without examples (or test cases). If I guessed right (see my edited solution) this, IMHO, is the soultion (I've managed to get 2 and 9 patterns)

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for!! Thank you very very much for your help, now it works flawlessly. :)